# How to split the string in one column into two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

```
id          value
-------     ---------------
1           ind.kolkatta
2           ind.pune
3           ind.mumbai
4           pak.lahore
5           pak.karachi
6           uae.sharjah
```

I want to return the following table:

```
id          contry       place
-------     ---------    ----------
1           ind          kolkatta
2           ind          pune
3           ind          mumbai
4           pak          lahore
5           pak          karachi
6           uae          sharjah
```

how can i do that using MSSQL.? I have already done in MYSQL using SUBSTRING_INDEX function

My MySql query

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`value`, '.', 1), '.', -1) as contry,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`value`, '.', 2), '.', -1) as place 
FROM   `table`
```

Comment: What happens with values like `ind.kol.katta`? _"I have already done in MYSQL"_ Then show it.

Comment: Either SQL-SERVER or MYSQL. It cant be both.

Comment: since am not using `MSSQL` you'll probably get answer from this resource http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms181984.aspx and [substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187748.aspx)

Comment: if it's sql server and in this case there is just 1 dot in between, you can just use the `PARSENAME` function like this: `PARSENAME(value,2) as country, PARSENAME(value,1) as place ...`

Answer (score 2):

Try following query:-

```
SELECT ID, SUBSTRING(value, 1, CHARINDEX('.', value)-1) AS contry,
SUBSTRING(value, CHARINDEX(',', value)+1, LEN(value)) AS  place
FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

This might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the Below Query helps you.

```
SELECT  id, SUBSTRING(value,1,3) as Country,SUBSTRING(value,4,LEN(value))AS Place FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  Id,
        LEFT(Value, CHARINDEX('.', Value)-1) AS Country, 
        STUFF(Value, 1, CHARINDEX('.', Value), '') AS Place
FROM    Table
```

As per `King King` comment I checked the following

```
SELECT  Id,
        PARSENAME(value, 2) AS Country, 
        PARSENAME(Value, 1) AS Place
FROM    Table
```

The above one worked, but I not sure about the version supported (I am using SSMS 2012).

Answer (score 0):

Or just loop and it will parse out how ever many periods you have in your name.

```
DECLARE @FILE VARCHAR(55) = 'ind.kol.katta.test1.test2.test3.test4'
DECLARE @FILEFUN AS VARCHAR(55) = LEFT(@FILE,CHARINDEX('.',@FILE))
DECLARE @FILENAMEOUTPUT AS TABLE(Name Varchar(55))

WHILE LEN(@FILE) > 0
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @FILENAMEOUTPUT
SELECT REPLACE(@FILEFUN,'.','')
SET @FILE = REPLACE(@FILE,@FILEFUN,'')
SET @FILEFUN = iif(CHARINDEX('.',@FILE)=0,@FILE,LEFT(@FILE,CHARINDEX('.',@FILE)))
END

SELECT * FROM @FILENAMEOUTPUT
```