# How can I separate one column to two column?

Tags: mysql

I have this table :

```
+---------+---------------+------------+  
| c_data  | c_characters  | c_numbers  |  
+---------+---------------+------------+  
| abc123  |               |            |
+---------+---------------+------------+  
| hb045   |               |            |
+---------+---------------+------------+  
| awrg5   |               |            |
+---------+---------------+------------+  
| xyz456  |               |            |
+---------+---------------+------------+
```

I want separate c_data characters and numbers,
then update to c_characters and c_numbers fields
How can I update field with query?

Comment: You can use regular expressions in your Query to do this. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html for guidance.

Comment: See this previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401849/how-to-split-the-string-in-one-column-into-two-columns

Comment: @DTH That question has a specific delimiter character. How would you do it here, where he just wants to split it into alphabetic and numeric parts?

Comment: @MattiasLindberg MySQL can only use regexp for testing whether a column matches, it doesn't have a function to return the part of the column that matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't (yet) have any [`REGEXP_REPLACE()` function like other databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql). You can give [issue 29781](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=29781) some love if you want.

But since you're only looking for digits as a separation criteria, you can write the following statement to get the result you're looking for:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET c_characters =
  replace(
    replace(
      replace(
        replace(
          replace(
            replace(
              replace(
                replace(replace(replace(c_data, '0', ''), '1', ''), '2', ''), '3', ''
              ), '4', ''
            ), '5', ''
          ), '6', ''
        ), '7', ''
      ), '8', ''
    ), '9', ''
  ),
  c_numbers =
    replace(v, 
      replace(
        replace(
          replace(
            replace(
              replace(
                replace(
                  replace(
                    replace(replace(replace(c_data, '0', ''), '1', ''), '2', ''), '3', ''
                  ), '4', ''
                ), '5', ''
              ), '6', ''
            ), '7', ''
          ), '8', ''
        ), '9', ''
      ), ''
    )
```

Comment: thanks, select query worked, now how can i update field? please change this select query to update query